# php preg_match_all, returning multiple optional values when available

Tags: php, regex, expression, preg-match-all

Example of the haystack:

```
INTERVENTIONS:
---------------------
Med Given: Versed - 9:50 PM Med Admin Route: Intravenous    Dosage: 20.00 MG
Med Given: Lidocaine - 9:50 PM  Med Admin Route: Intravenous    Dosage: 150.00 MG
Med Given: Succinylcholine - 9:50 PM    Med Admin Route: Intravenous    Dosage: 200.00 MG
Med Given: Oxygen - 7:23 PM Dosage: 2.00 L/MIN
Med Given: Vancomycin
Med Given: Fentanyl
Med Given: Dopamine
Med Given: Dextrose
Med Given: Gentamicin
```

As you cans see, sometimes there are times ( - H:MM AM/PM), sometimes "Med Admin Route: ..." and "Dosage: ...", I always want the name (Versed, Oxygen, etc) and if available - the time (H:MM AM/PM), route (Intravenous, Oral, etc) and dosage (20.00 MG, 2.00 L/MIN, etc) all stored in an array.  I've thought that I've had it in the past but when I throw a different haystack at it it fails...  Also note that it appears that sometimes there is a tab instead of a space between the variables like time-Admin or Admin-Dosage...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('~Med Given: ((?:(?!-\s*\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} (?:A|P)M|Med Admin Route:|Dosage:|$).)+)(?:\s*-\s*(.*?(?:A|P)M))?(?:\s*Med Admin Route:((?:(?!Dosage:|$).)+))?(?:\s*Dosage:\s*(.*))?~',$content,$matches);
```

Got the job done thanks to the guys at phpfreaks.com

Answer (score 1):

Luckily for you, I have some time on my hands during my lunch break :)

In regex, `?` after an expression means that it will accept one or zero occurences. Per example:

```
preg_match('/^(foo)?bar/', 'foobar'); // 1
preg_match('/^(foo)?bar/', 'bar');    // also 1
```

In your case, it is a little hard to do by regex, but feasible anyway:

```
preg_match_all('/Med Given: (?<name>[A-Za-z ]+)(- (?<time>[0-9:]+ (AM|PM)))?( +Med Admin Route: (?<route>\w+))?( +Dosage: (?<dosage>.*))?/', $data, $matches);
```

Then post-process the array:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($matches['name'] as $key => $name) {
    $result = array('name'=>$name);
    if (!empty($matches['time'][$key])) $result['time'] = $matches['time'][$key];
    if (!empty($matches['route'][$key])) $result['route'] = $matches['route'][$key];
    if (!empty($matches['dosage'][$key])) $result['dosage'] = $matches['dosage'][$key];
    $results[] = $result;
}
print_r($results);
```

This should give you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Versed 
            [time] => 9:50 PM
            [route] => Intravenous
            [dosage] => 20.00 MG
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Lidocaine 
            [time] => 9:50 PM
            [route] => Intravenous
            [dosage] => 150.00 MG
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Succinylcholine 
            [time] => 9:50 PM
            [route] => Intravenous
            [dosage] => 200.00 MG
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Oxygen 
            [time] => 7:23 PM
            [dosage] => 2.00 L/MIN
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Vancomycin
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => Fentanyl
        )
    [6] => Array
        (
            [name] => Dopamine
        )
    [7] => Array
        (
            [name] => Dextrose
        )
    [8] => Array
        (
            [name] => Gentamicin
        )
)
```

The only issue here is the "Med Admin Route" bit. It must be a single word (i.e.: no spaces).

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, but I only get the name and time with that pattern...  Here is what I get from the first three meds:

`Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Versed 
            [time] => 9:50 PM
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Lidocaine 
            [time] => 9:50 PM
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Succinylcholine 
            [time] => 9:50 PM
        )

)`

Comment: @jreed121: That's odd because it works as expected for me (the output I posted is the actual output I get). There might be a twist that is not in your example, is the input data you tried the exact same thing as the one you posted?

Comment: yeah, it's the same.  Here is an example that includes all of the potential combination I can think of:`
Med Given: Versed - 9:50 PM Med Admin Route: Intravenous Dosage: 20.00 MG
Med Given: Lidocaine - 9:50 PM Med Admin Route: Intravenous Dosage: 150.00 MG
Med Given: Succinylcholine - 9:50 PM Med Admin Route: Nasal prongs Dosage: 200.00 MG
Med Given: Vancomycin Med Admin Route: Oral Dosage: 20.00 MG
Med Given: Fentanyl twowords
Med Given: Dopamine Dosage: 200.00 MG
Med Given: Oxygen - 7:23 PM Dosage: 2.00 L/MIN
Med Given: Dextrose Med Admin Route: Intravenous
Med Given: Gentamicin`

Comment: @jreed121: Can you update your question with this dataset? I don't get it, it works fine for me.